# Argument errors passing function to another function

Tags: c++, fibonacci

```
#include <stdio.h>

double soma ( double a, double b){
    return a+b;
}

double mult ( double a, double b){
    return a*b;
}

double sub( double a, double b){
    return a-b;
}

double div ( double a, double b){
    return a/b;
}

double fib_ninja ( double (* fn)(double a, double b),int init ){
    int i=0;
    int tam=10;
    int acum = init;
    int ant=0;

    for (i=0 ; i<tam ; i++){
        acum = fn(acum,ant);
        ant = acum;
        printf ("%f",acum);
    }
    return acum;
}

int main(){
    int op;
    printf("escolha a operação desejada: 1(soma),2(multiplicação),3(subtraçaõ,4(divisão)) ");
    scanf("%d",&op);        
    if(op==1){ 
        fib_ninja((soma (6.0, 2.0)),0);
    }
    if(op==2){
        fib_ninja((mult ,6.0, 2.0),1);
    }
    if(op==3) {
        fib_ninja((sub ,6.0, 2.0),0);
    }
    if(op==4){
        fib_ninja((div ,6.0, 2.0),1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The error says

```
In function 'main':
Line 39: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'fib_ninja'
Line 42: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'fib_ninja'
Line 45: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'fib_ninja'
Line 48: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'fib_ninja'
```

link from this http://codepad.org/HTLeR6Jh

Comment: I always feel like I'm getting trolled when i read a title with a misspelling.

Comment: Always tag with the language you're using, and please use a more descriptive title.

Comment: sorry, i not have a good english, i'm from brazil. ;/
the education here is a crappy.

Comment: `double fib_ninja ( double (* fn)(double a, double b),int init ){` can you really declare a method like this....?

Comment: @progenhard: of course you can...

Comment: @SigTerm can you explain `double (* fn)` how this works?

Comment: @progenhard As any other declaration. If you type it as an expression, you get the result type. So it's a pointer to a function which takes two doubles and returns a double. [See here](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=double+%28*fn%29%28double%2C+double%29).

Comment: @progenhard: It's a function pointer - pointer to function that returns double and takes two non-const double arguments. Normally people typedef things like this (to make them easier to read), but if you write function pointers without typedefs (like in this question), compiler will recognize them anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I'm trying to infer what you're trying to do here, so let me know if I misinterpret.

First: `acum` and `ant` in `fib_ninja()` need to be `double`.

Second: I can't tell what you're trying to do with the values `6.0` and `2.0`. They are not declared in the signature or used anywhere in `fib_ninja()`, and there's no point passing them to your `soma()` et al. functions, since `fib_ninja()` is clearly meant to take a function pointer, not a `double` returned from executing those functions. Remove the arguments `6.0` and `2.0` (and the superfluous parentheses) from the calls to `fib_ninja` and that'll get rid of the errors.

E.g.:
`fib_ninja(soma, 0);`
`fib_ninja(mult, 1);`

After fixing these things, your code still won't do much. If you have further problems once you work on it more, post another question.

Answer (score 0):

The program is a bit confused and probably won't do anything useful without some changes.  I'd suggest posting the question you are trying to answer.

Notwithstanding that, the immediate problem with the compiler is fairly straightforward.

```
double Add(double x, double y);

int main()
{
    // The following will execute Add() and
    // pass the result to func1() as a double.
    func1(Add(1.0, 2.0));

    // The following will pass a function pointer
    // for Add() to func2()
    func2(Add);

    return 0;
}
```

I think you want something like `func2()` above, but you have written something more like `func1()`.